# Apple IIGS emulator?

Tags: software-recommendation, apple, emulation

What is the best quality Apple IIGS emulator for Ubuntu that is relatively easy to install?

I have tried KEGS, but get the following (working without probs on my Windows partition):

> Preparing X Windows graphics system
>
> Visual 0
>
> id: 00000021, screen: 0, depth: 24, class: 4
>
> red: 00ff0000, green: 0000ff00, blue: 000000ff
>
> cmap
>
> size: 256, bits_per_rgb: 8 Chose
>   visual: 0, max_colors: -1
>
> Will use shared memory for X
>
> pipes: pipe_fd =
>   4, 5  pipe2_fd: 6,7 open /dev/dsp
>   failed, ret: -1, errno:2
>
> parent dying,
>   could not get sample rate from child
>
> ret: 0, fd: 6 errno:11

Answer (score 4):

This is likely because KEGS uses the OSS sound system; it is originally a port from HP-UX, and most of the other Linux sound APIs do not exist on other Unix variants. Try one of the following:

padsp kegs

aoss kegs

Comment: padsp also performs much much better than aoss

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried [KEGS](http://kegs.sourceforge.net/) from Sourceforge ?

Answer (score 0):

As of 2021 ...

[gsplus](https://apple2.gs/plus/) is the best one based off the the KEGS and gsport projects.

I use it as the final step for a Makefile building Apple II projects.

That Makefile is based off of [blondihacks](http://www.quinndunki.com/blondihacks) makefile.